# Sourcetree pull request throwing: Excepetion: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

whenever I make a fetch and pull in Sourcetree I get an exeception with the following error:

0 [main] sh 4148 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

then it "generates" sh.exe.stackdump

I am a newbie to sourcetree but this error keeps recurring. The pull request does not really succeed as it still shows that I have stuff to pull. Any ideas to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so the answer to this was: I am using embedded Git in Sourcetree and It turned out it was 'broke' and needed to update it. That solved my problem. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

My sh.exe.stackdump did not leave me alone even after I updated the embedded Git.
What worked for me was to use system git.

Tools -> Options -> Git -> Use System Git